# How do I change my view back to normal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was mucking around with the options menu and I changed my view on the game so it went all bendy and weird. It was fun for a few days but now I want to change it back to normal and I don't know how!
Please help!

Comment: Please help! Trying everything but it is not working. :(

Comment: A screenshot of your current graphics settings might help us to identify what it was that you changed

Comment: I know it is not the fov

Comment: Here is how it looks

Comment: Sos my internet is poop so it won't let me send the screen shot >:(

Answer (score 2):

You most likely changed your Field of View (FOV). A low FOV will look zoomed in, whereas a high FOV may distorted.

You can change it back (70 is the default) with the upper left slider in your options menu.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Its the FOV, change it up and it zooms in, if you change it back it zooms out so you can make it to your standards.

Comment: Sox it is definitely not fov.

Comment: I have tryed the fov but it is not that.